# Hystrix Turbine aggregate data

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I am using turbine to aggregate data from hystrix. Everything goes well when I try to get data with hystrix(localhost:23002/hystrix.strean). However,when I try to use turbine to get data, it shows nothing.
Here's my configuration.

```
server:  
    port: 23002  
spring:  
    application:  
      name: hystrix-1  
eureka:  
    client:  
    serviceUrl:  
      defaultZone: http://t2.dcfservice.com:23001/eureka/  
  instance:  
    hostname: localhost  
    metadataMap:   
      cluster : MAIN
```

```
spring:  
  application.name: microservice-hystrix-turbine  
server:  
  port: 23111  
security.basic.enabled: false  
turbine:  
  aggregator:  
    clusterConfig: MAIN       
    appConfig: hystrix-1  
    clusterNameExpression: metadata['cluster']  

eureka:  
  client:  
    serviceUrl:  
      defaultZone: http://t2.dcfservice.com:23001/eureka/
```

I can get data with URL:localhost:23002/hystrix.stream
My goal is to get data with URL localhost:23111/turbine.stream?cluster=MAIN

Answer (score 1):

If you posted your yml with exact indentation that is being used in your server, the indentation of below are wrong.

```
turbine:  
  aggregator:  
    clusterConfig: MAIN       
  appConfig: hystrix-1  
  clusterNameExpression: metadata['cluster']
```

`appConfig` and `clusterNameExpression` must be a child of `turbine`, not `aggregator`